# Print Index location of input after Merge sorting

Tags: java, output, mergesort

I've written a program to implement merge sort of a set. I am able to print the index location of the chosen integer based on the initial set provided. Any suggestions on how to print the location of the chosen integer after the sort is processed? I believe it would be in the first class file public int LinearSearch.

```
public class LinearArray {

        private int[] data;//array of values
        private static final Random generator = new Random();

        //create array of given size and fill with random numbers
        public  LinearArray(int size)
        {
            data = new int[ size ];//create space for array

           //fill array with random ints in range 10-99
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
           data[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(90);


        }//end LinearArray constructor

        //calls recursive split method to being merge sorting
        public void sort()
        {
            sortArray(0, data.length -1);//split entire array
        }//end method sort

        //splits array, sorts subarrays and merges subarrays into sorted       
        private void sortArray(int low, int high)
        {
            //test base case; size of array equals 1
            if((high - low) >= 1)//if not base case
        {
            int middle1 =(low + high) / 2;//calculate middle of array
            int middle2 = middle1 + 1;//calculate next element over

            //output split step
            System.out.println("split: " + subarray(low, high));
            System.out.println("       " + subarray(low, middle1));
            System.out.println("        " + subarray(middle2, high));

            //split array in half; sort each half(recursive calls)
            sortArray(low, middle1);//first half of array
            sortArray(middle2, high);//second half of array

            //merge two sorted arrays after split calls return
            merge(low, middle1, middle2, high);
        }//end if
    }//end method

    //merge two sorted subarrays into one sorted subarray
    private void merge(int left, int middle1, int middle2, int right)
    {
        int leftIndex = left; //index into left subarray
        int rightIndex = middle2; //index into right subarray
        int combinedIndex = left; //index into temporary working array
        int[] combined = new int[data.length];//working array

        //output two subarrays before merging
        System.out.println("merge: " + subarray(left, middle1));
        System.out.println("       " + subarray(middle2, right));

        //merge arrays until reaching end of either
        while(leftIndex <= middle1 && rightIndex <= right)
        {
            //place smaller of two current elements into result
            //and move to next space in arrays
            if(data[leftIndex] <= data[rightIndex])
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];
            else
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[rightIndex++];
        }//end while

        //if left array is empty
        if(leftIndex == middle2)
            //copy in rest of right array
            while(rightIndex <= right)
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[rightIndex++];
        else//right array is empty
            //copy in rest of left array
            while(leftIndex <= middle1)
                combined[combinedIndex++] = data[leftIndex++];

        //copy values back into original array
        for(int i = left; i <= right; i++)
            data[i] = combined[i];

        //output merged array
        System.out.println("      " + subarray(left, right));
        System.out.println();

    }//end method merge
    //perform a linear search on the data
    public int linearSearch (int searchKey)
    {
        //loop through array sequentially
        for(int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
            if (data[index] == searchKey)
                return index;//return index of integer

        return -1;//integer was not found
    }//end mmethod linearSearch

    public String subarray(int low, int high)
    {
        StringBuilder temporary = new StringBuilder();

        //ouptput spaces for alignment
        for(int i = 0; i < low; i++)
            temporary.append("   ");

        //output elements left in array
        for(int i = low; i <= high; i++)
            temporary.append(" " + data[i]);
        return temporary.toString();
    }//end method subarray
    //method to output values in array
    public String toString()
    {
        return Arrays.toString(data);
    }//end method toString

}//end class
```

2nd Class File:

```
public class LinearSearchTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //create Scanner object to input data
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);




        int searchInt;//search key
        int position;//location of search key in array

        //create array and output it
        LinearArray searchArray = new LinearArray (10);
        System.out.println(searchArray + "\n");//print array


        //get input from user
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer value (-1 to quit):");
        searchInt = input.nextInt();//read first int from user

        //repeatedly input an integer: -1 terminates the program
        while(searchInt != -1)
        {
            //perform linear search
            position = searchArray.linearSearch(searchInt);

            if (position == -1)//integer was not found
                System.out.println("The integer "+ searchInt + " was not found.\n");


            else//integer was found
                searchArray.sort();//sort array
                System.out.println("The integer " + searchInt + " was found in "
                        + "position " + position +  ".\n");


            //get input from user
            System.out.print("Plese enter an integer value (-1 to quit):");
            searchInt = input.nextInt();//read next int from user


        }//end while


    }//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: do you know what the program is doing ? Unless I did not understand correctly,  you want to do a linear search on your sorted array,, if so just call the method linearSerch on the sorted array object.

Comment: You are correct on what I need. I'm stuck on doing that process. I understand the method you are referencing, but the object? would that be  searchArray.sort() in the 2nd test file?

Comment: Yes, I dont totally understand why you want to sort it if you find the input integer but calling `position = searchArray.linearSearch(searchInt);`after you have done the sort() would give you the answer.
After sorting the original `position` variable would be wrong.. you need to do that step after you have sorted your array.

Comment: I might be miss understanding what I am being asked. Each call to the recursive method should check one index in the array.

Comment: The recursive calls implement [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), it sorts the array. Please go through the link for understanding the algorithm.

Comment: My bad I got it. Thank you.